# _textChanged event is giving me error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, textchanged

I'm new to C# so still finding my way around.

I have a button I want to enable only when a user enter text to textbox.
I get this error - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Here is the related code (without the using and variables):

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Make sure to edit Settings tab.");
        InitializeComponent();
        if (startTextBox.Text == "0")    // Checks to see if a textbox has some text other than zero. if no than the user cannot press button1 yet.
        {
            button1.IsEnabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            button1.IsEnabled = true;
        }

    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (radioButton1.IsChecked == false)
        {
            label17.Content = "No Hourly wage was set.";
        }

    }

    private void add(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    /// here is a very long method so I've removed its content.


    }


    public void printTime()
    {

        int Sum = (this.EndInt - this.StartInt);
        int Money = (Sum * this.L1001);


        label16.Content = Sum;
        label17.Content = Money;
        if ((textBox1.Text == "0") && ((textBox2.Text == "0") || (textBox3.Text == "0")))
        {
            label17.Content = "No Hourly wage was set.";
        }
    }

    public void printTime2()
    {

        int Sum = (this.EndInt - this.StartInt);
        MessageBox.Show("Is it possible that you've worked - " + Sum + " Hours?");
    }

    public void printTime3()
    {

        int Sum = (this.EndInt - this.StartInt);
        int Money = (Sum * this.L1001);

        label16.Content = Sum;
        label17.Content = Money;
        if (textBox1.Text == "0")
        {
            label17.Content = "No Hourly wage was set.";
        }
    }


    public int Convert(String S)
    {
        int i = int.Parse(S);
        return i;
    }


    // Input Validation For Excepting Integers Only!
    private void input(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    { CheckIsNumeric(e); }
    private void CheckIsNumeric(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        int result; if (!(int.TryParse(e.Text, out result) || e.Text == "."))
        { e.Handled = true; MessageBox.Show("Numbers Only"); }

    }


    private void startTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        button1.IsEnabled = true;
    }




}
```

}

Comment: where do you get the error, i don't think its amongst the code sample you published

Answer (score 1):

It's the scope problem.  You didn't show where button1 is defined.  But inside your event handler **startTextBox_TextChanged**, button1 definition is nowhere to be found (actually it needs to be instantiated as well).  Since you try to invoke a method on an object (button1) which has not been instantiated yet, that exception was thrown.

If you post more than just those snippets, either I or someone else might be able to further help you.

Comment: I've edited my snippets to show the entire code minus a very big event code for clicking a button (private void add(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)). Can you find me the problem?